# How to load all Managed Metadata values from a Term Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

Short version: **How can I load all the available options for a Managed Metadata field in PowerApps?**

Long version:

I have a PowerApps app that is working properly, but the users want to be able to add data while offline and for it to sync back when online again. There are some pages in the official PowerApps site about how to do that with collections and functions like `SaveData()` and `LoadData()` (I have included some links below for reference, in case someone needs), but I am facing some issues with some "special" fields.

For the Lookup columns, I am trying to load a collection with all the values when online to use as cache when offline, then `Patch()` the values in the item, it seems to work OK based on just a few tests (if you ignore the fact that users might delete the item in the referenced list while offline).

I was trying to do the same for the **Managed Metadata columns**, to load all the values and deal with a complex `Patch()` later, but **it seems that the functions are limited at working with just the 20 first items**. So something like `ClearCollect(MyCollection, Choices(ListName.ColumnName))` doesn't work as `Choices()` are not getting all the values. Even the `Filter()` function is executing the filter considering only the first 20 items.

**Is there any way around the imposed limitations or any way to overcome/change the limits? Am I missing another way to do this in PowerApps?**

---

Links for reference about how to make an app work while offline:

- https://powerapps.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/build-offline-apps-with-new-powerapps-capabilities/
- https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/implementing-offline-capability-in-your-app/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and in the end, just created a collection using the `TaxonomyHiddenList` and `filter` for the field you want.

ClearCollect(CollectionName, Filter(TaxonomyHiddenList , IdForTermSet = "[guid of term]"));

Now looking to find how to save using the patch.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the TaxonomyHiddenList just have the terms that were used in the site collection. So if a new term is created you are not going to see it and you might show terms that don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`TaxonomyHiddenList` is not a good solution in my opinion, because it will only work if all terms are already used inside the site collection.

I created a **blog** post for one of my customers, on how to solve this issue without the use of any premium features.

This solution will also give more flexibility in the way of searching (**StartsWith**, **Contains**, ...)

https://www.xylos.com/blog/powerapps-display-more-than-20-items-for-managed-metadata-fields/

Comment: Seems links is broken